# How to change the Text of TMsgDlgButtons "Yes" and "No" Buttons in RAD Studio XE?

Tags: c++, c++builder, vcl, c++builder-xe

I want to change the Text of `YES` and `NO` buttons in a message box.

```
CModalWndManager::ShowMessageBox(AnsiString::LoadStr(IDS_NOT_SUPPORTED).c_str(), mtWarning, TMsgDlgButtons() << mbYes << mbNo, mbOK == mrYes);
```

Instead of `YES`, I want `"Switch Mode"`, and for `NO` I want `"Exit"`.

Is it possible to do this in RAD Studio XE?

Comment: What is `CModalWndManager::ShowMessageBox()` calling internally to actually display the message box?  If `Dialogs::MessageDlg()`, then on Vista+ with themes enabled and `UseLatestCommonDialogs=true` it calls [`TaskDialogIndirect()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760544.aspx), so the text comes from the OS itself based on the user's locale. If themes are disabled or `UseLatestCommonDialogs=false`, it calls `CreateMessageDialog()` instead, which creates a custom VCL `TForm`. You can call `CreateMessageDialog()` directly and then customize the `TForm` however you want

Comment: Why are you using `AnsiString` in XE?  You should be using `UnicodeString` instead, especially if `CModalWndManager::ShowMessageBox()` is using a VCL dialog box internally.

Comment: @RemyLebeau  Thank you Very much for your Answer... Really appriciate... I used CreateMessageDialog and modified TForm Property as needed.. and it works.. Thanx from India.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://bcbjournal.org/articles/vol4/0003/Making_marvelous_message_dialogs.htm

```
TForm* Dlg = CreateMessageDialog(
    "Purge Warp Core?", mtConfirmation,
    TMsgDlgButtons() << mbYes << mbNo);
  TButton* yb = dynamic_cast<TButton *>
    (Dlg->FindComponent("Yes"));
  if (yb)
    yb->Caption = "Affirmative";
  TButton* nb = dynamic_cast<TButton *>
    (Dlg->FindComponent("No"));
  if (nb)
    nb->Caption = "Negative";
  int Rslt = Dlg->ShowModal();
  switch (Rslt) {
    case mrYes: ;// do "Yes" stuff
    case mrNo:  ;// do "No" stuff
```

Comment: I know the article shows this, but using `dynamic_cast` is unnecessary. If you ask for a Yes button, you will get one, and `FindComponent()` will not return NULL. Since you know a `TButton` is used, you can use `static_cast` instead, and omit the NULL check. Same with the other buttons

Comment: Good but Add some `break;` inside the switch